# My query doesn't return all data from a column

Tags: t-sql

One of my column has been set to nvarchar(max). When I query that column it only return 256 characters. I have checked the length of data and it has more than 7000 characters.

How can I get all characters instead of losing any?

```
# select ValidationKey from UserProductAccountProvider
```

Comment: Where does it not return the full column length? In SQL Server Mgmt Studio? Yes - that has a limit - but if you run that same query from your code, you'll get back the whole column.

Comment: I tried to return this on a text file.

Comment: In that case - we need to see your code. Just from your question, there's no way to answer this....

Comment: Or are you - by any chance - exporting using the `Import/Export` wizard? That does have certain length limitations (and I believe it will truncate certain columns at 256 chars, come to think of it....)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SSMS, select Tools menu, then Options, Query Results, SQL Server, Results To Text.  Change the “Maximum number of characters displayed in each column” value from 256 to what ever number you want up to 8192.  After you click OK the setting will be saved. The setting doesn’t actually take effect until you start a new query window.

As marc_s said, from your code you'll get the full text column.

Answer (score 3):

Next to the UI setting that David pointed at there are two more settings that have impact on the amount of returned data.

2: select Tools menu, then Options, Query Results, SQL Server, Result to Grid. Change the value 'Non XML data'. This value tell you how many characters are in the grid available. You can get them with copy. It looks like the default limit is larger than the limit of the clipboard (I get at most 43kB Characters).

3: there is a setting in studio that limits the amount of returned data. It is per session. It can be found via Tools menu, then Options, Query Execution. Change the value of 'SET TEXTSIZE'. One can validate and change the value in a SQL batch:

```
SELECT @@textsize;
```

You can set it to e.g 100kB with:

```
SET textsize 102400;
```

Normally the UI setting is low about 256, but more data is available.

These three settings have all impact on what you see (or get).

When you really like to examine very large result sets you can print the result in the message window:

```
DECLARE @s AS NVARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @LineLength AS int = 4000;
-- you might need a cursor when you have many rows;
SELECT TOP 1 @s = large_text FROM ....
WHILE LEN(@s) > @LineLength  BEGIN
    print SUBSTRING(@s,1, @LineLength);
    SET @s = SUBSTRING(@s,@LineLength, LEN(@s));
END
```